# Re-encoding entire code base from UTF-16 to UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, utf-16

Does anyone have a good way to re-encode all the *.java file in a directory from UTF-16 to UTF-8?

Comment: What enviroment are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this in your favorite POSIX compatible shell (while you're in the source directory):

```
find -name "*.java" | while read f; do
   mv "$f" "$f.bak"
   iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 < "$f.bak" > "$f"
done
```

Comment: You've got `-f` and `-t` reversed, I think. Your call converts from UTF-8 to UTF-16 :-)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with shell scripts, but shouldn't it be `read f;` ?

Comment: @Jochen: darn! That's what I get for posting untested shell scripts. Yes, of course the argument to `read` must be the same as is used later on (i.e. replacing every `$f` with `$j` would have been an equally valid fix).

Comment: Shell scripts are arcane and contain weird defaults and conventions, so I wouldn't have wondered if j would be used in some weird way :)